# NSUnknownKeyException when adding object with update true

Tags: swift, realm

So I have modeled an object as such

```
class Post: Object {
    let postId = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var postImage : PostImage?
    dynamic var postUser: User?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "postId"
    }
 }
```

and I am trying to persist it like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.beginWrite()
let post = Post()
post.postId.value = json["image"]["image_id"].intValue
realm.add(post, update: true)
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

However when the object is a new one and has not been stored yet I get:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key (null).'

There has to be something I am doing wrong because the documentation states that Realms

```
public func add(object: Object, update: Bool = false)
```

will create the object if one with the primary key is not present.

Any help or pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. You found a bug. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3671) and have submitted a PR to resolve that.